# Angular Show More Pagination

Tags: angular, typescript, pagination

I am trying to implement show more pagination on my angular project. What I am trying is to show maximum of 8 products per page, and by clicking *Show More* button product list expands for another 4 products. I followed [this tutorial](http://www.angulartutorial.net/2017/09/angular-show-moreless-pagination.html), and my compiler says this:
[image]
None of those variables is string. event is a model that contains multiple data types, and I am making array of it. Here is the .ts of this component.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { EventService } from '../services/event/event.service';
import { Event } from '../shared/models/event'
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent {

  events:Event[]=[];
  startPage : Number;
  paginationLimit:Number
  constructor(private eventService:EventService, private route:ActivatedRoute){
    this.startPage = 0;
    this.paginationLimit = 8;
   }
   showMoreItems()
   {
      this.paginationLimit = Number(this.paginationLimit) + 3;        
   }
   showLessItems()
   {
     this.paginationLimit = Number(this.paginationLimit) - 3;
   }

  ngOnInit(): void{
    this.events=this.eventService.getAll();
    this.route.params.subscribe(params=>{
      if(params['searchTerm'])
        this.events=this.eventService.getAll().filter(events=>events.name.toLowerCase().includes(params['searchTerm'].toLowerCase()));
      else
      this.events=this.eventService.getAll();
    })
  }

}
```

Can you help me to figure out what is the problem here?

Comment: It's not immediately obvious to me what is going wrong here. Have you imported `CommonModule` into the module which declares `HomeComponent` (as this is responsible for allowing `*ngFor` to be used within a component)?

Comment: Yes, I have imported CommonModule

Comment: For me it looks like the slice pipe doesn't accept the array, only string. Angular's slice pipe does accept both. Do you maybe have another selfdefined slice pipe in project, that is for string only?

Comment: No, I have not.